# IOS delegation not working when the app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am currently implementing the delegation in IOS.

But when I put a breakpoint in the XCode and I do some thing which is going to respond back after fe seconds like HTTP request

Then I am checking invoking the delegate method.

But the break point is reached, but it reached only if I restore the application from background. Even sometimes the NSLog is alos not printing when the app in background.

Is this a default behaviour of XCode, can anyone please help me on this

Can we say no normal method calling functionality will work in a background app?

Comment: App in background completely freezes. Only a few cases, like Remote Notification or Navigation can interrupt backgrounded app.

Answer (score 2):

If you need your app to continue operating after being sent to background (your HTTP or network transactions), then you need to execute those operations as a Background task from the beginning. Look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

Table 3-1 on this page shows the various background modes you can register for:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23

While it's possible to register for one of the background modes, just for the sake of being able to du background stuff, it's highly discouraged as Apple might reject the app if you register some background mode that is not necessary for the purpose of your app.

Not knowing exactly what you need, maybe "Background fetch" could solve your problem, since you mention HTTP request?